# Let ABC be any triangle and let D, E and F be the midpoints of AB, BC and CA. Let X be the point on BC such that AX is perpendicular to BC.

Tags: geometry

Let ABC be any triangle and let D, E and F be the midpoints of AB, BC and CA.  Let X be the point on BC such that AX is perpendicular to BC.  Prove that X lies on the circumcircle of DEF.

Is it related to 9 points circle?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Consider the figure . All the $4$ small triangles are congruent , and all corresponding line segments are parallel . ( By Midpoint  Theorem )

We have $\angle FDE = \angle C $ . Also , $\angle FAX = 90 - \angle C$

Since $FD \parallel BC $ , $FG \perp AX$ and bisects it .

$\therefore \triangle FAX $ is isosceles. It follows that $\angle FXA = 90 - \angle C$ .

Therefore , we have:- $$\angle FXE + \angle FDE = ( 90 + 90 - \angle C) + \angle C = 180 $$ 
Therefore , the opposite angles of quadrilateral $FXED$ are supplementary.

**It follows that all the vertices lie on a circle .**

Other cases , where the triangle is right or obtuse , can be proven by similar angle chasing .

**Note:-** Through this proof , we have proved that the points of intersection of the altitudes with the sides , and the midpoints of the sides , are all concyclic . We have proved that $6$ of the $9$ points of the $9$-point circle are concyclic. To prove the existence of the $9$-point circle , it remains to be shown that the midpoints of the lines joining the orthrocentre and the vertices are concyclic as well.